# MySQL: How to use triggers to make multiple updates or conditional updates

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table that logs all our user and client information (sessionEvent). It logs things like page views, logins, email views, etc. These different Types are designated by a foreign key for type. The table structure for my sessionEvent table looks like the following:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| typeID | userID        | clientID              | emailID        |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1      | 12345         | 12                    | NULL                  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2      | 54321         | 5                     | NULL                  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 3      | 78945         | 4                     | 5555                  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

All the columns in this table are foreign keys, assume the following for the types:

- typeID 1 = login
- typeID 2 = page view
- typeID 3 = email view

Every time an event takes place in our app a record is added to this sessionEvent table. There are currently 100 million rows in this table so it gets a bit inefficient to hit this table for summary reporting data.

I'm experimenting with triggers to increment a summary field in the appropriate related tables. I have been partially successful with this attempt, but having trouble with making conditional updates to appropriate tables. For example, here is my current trigger after insert on the sessionEvent table:

```
UPDATE client, user
SET
    client.clientLogins = client.clientLogins + 1,
    user.userLogins = user.userLogins + 1,
WHERE 
    client.clientID = new.clientID
    AND user.userID = new.userID
    AND new.typeID = 1
```

This works and increments the respective login field for both the client and user tables when a record is inserted with the typeID = 1. Now where I am starting to get stuck is that I can't seem to add multiple update queries within a single trigger.

So if an email is viewed, a record is added to this sessionEvent table with the typeID = 3. I would like to use the same trigger to update the summary field for views in my email table. I've explored case statements a bit, but can't seem to find the right solution. So basically, here's what I would like to accomplish:

When a record is added to the sessionEvent table the trigger runs an update on certain fields in certain tables based on the type. I know this syntax is wrong, but something along these lines.

```
if typeID = 1 then update user, client
  set user.userLogins = user.userLogins + 1,
  client.clientLogins = client.clientLogins + 1

if typeID = 3 then update email
  set views = views + 1
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Here's the sample trigger code I would like to run

Here is a sample of the trigger I would like to run:

```
UPDATE client, user
 SET
  client.clientLogins = client.clientLogins + 1,
  user.userLogins = user.userLogins + 1,
 WHERE 
  client.clientID = new.clientID
  AND user.userID = new.userID
  AND new.typeID = 1;

UPDATE email
 SET
  emailViews = emailViews + 1
 WHERE 
  email.emailID = new.emailID
  AND new.typeID = 3;
```

Full trigger DDL:

```
CREATE TRIGGER
 after_sessionEvent_insert after insert ON sessionEvent
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  UPDATE client, user
   SET client.clientLogins = client.clientLogins + 1,
    user.userLogins = user.userLogins + 1
   WHERE client.clientID = new.clientID
    AND user.userID = new.userID
    AND new.sessionEventTypeID = 1;
  UPDATE email
   SET emailViews = emailViews + 1
   WHERE emailID = new.emailID
    AND new.sessionEventTypeID = 3;
END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can perform various dml inside a same trigger. You should publish the full trigger code so we can investigate it.

Also make sure you do not cause an infinite loop with your triggers, like update on table a trigger insert in table b, and insert in tabke b causes an update on table.

Comment: Please piblish the FULL trigger DDL

Comment: Just added the full DDL for the trigger.

Comment: The error I am getting is on the line between the two UPDATES

Comment: I'm an idiot. I wasn't using the Delimiter. Rookie mistake, but thanks for helping me through my problems